# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: active SupportMapFragment{17456771} has cleared index: -1

Tags: android, android-fragments

Getting this error When opening new Activity like PlacePicker Activity or Camera from fragment.

Comment: add crash log with question

Comment: also you should add your code